# Is there any way to check programmatically whether SAS URL for Azure blob storage expired or not?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Is there any way to check programmatically whether SAS URL for Azure blob storage expired or not? I've looked through MSDN but couldn't find any useful information on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how your SAS is generated. If it's generated by account key directly, you can check `se` query parameter for expiry time, for example:
[image]

If you SAS is generated by stored access policy, the expiry time can't be directly found from SAS string, you have to get properties of the corresponding stored access policy from Azure Blob Storage service, here is [the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-container-acl).